# pass dynamic value in regular expression in jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to replace whole word in a string.

**Here is my code**

```
$new_val = $val.replace(/\ba\b/, "");
```

It replaces a woth blank ,it is working fine but i want to use dynamic value in the place of `a` .how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed version of Shivdhwaj Pandey's answer:

```js
$val = " a b c";
$stringToFind = "a";
var re = new RegExp("\\b" + $stringToFind + "\\b");
$new_val = $val.replace(re, "");
console.log($new_val);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression)

Comment: Hi,
above expression works fine but if $stringToFind is prefix with '+'  then it gives error

 Invalid regular expression: /\b+school\b/: Nothing to repeat